# deleting the rest of lines after specific charactar

Tags: regex, notepad++, emeditor

for example i have a file that have same format of data

```
DATA102:991n| DATA | Data222
DATA10:22 | DATA | Data222
DATA102:991 | DATA | Data222
DATA10:22 | DATA | Data222
DATA102:991 | DATA | Data222
DATA10:22 | DATA | Data222
```

I want to Delete every thing after " | " for example i want this output

```
DATA102:991n
DATA10:22 
DATA102:991 
DATA10:22 
DATA102:991 
DATA10:22
```

how i can achieve that with regex ?
i tried Find: `(.*|).*` then replace `/1`

but it didn't work i want to delete everything after `|`

Comment: Match `/ *\|.*/` and replace with empty string

Comment: @anubhava doesn't work , can you put it as an answer and test it ?

Comment: Don't use `/` in notepad++. Just `<space>*\|.*` Use a space instead of `<space>`

Comment: @anubhava still didn't work

Comment: @hewman There are a couple of solutions that should work for you, they are below. However, the text you have might be actually different from the one you shared. Are you sure there are regular spaces? Are there tabs? Soft spaces? Are there any invisible chars, like ZWJ (zero width joiner) between words? I [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65553631/3832970) `[ \t]*\|.*`, but you might as well try `[^\S\r\n]*\|.*`, or even `[^\w|\r\n]*\|.*`

Answer (score 3):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^|]+\K.*$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    [^|]+       # 1 or more any character that is not a pipe
    \K          # forget all we have seen until this position
    .*          # 1 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use

**Find What**:     `[ \t]*\|.*`
**Replace with**: *empty*

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/flSvns/1). *Details*:

- `[ \t]*` - zero or more spaces or tab
- `\|` - a `|` char
- `.*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same format of data, another option is to make the pattern a bit more specific matching the word characters, colon and the pipe.

In the replacement use an empty string.

```
^\w+:\w+\K\h*\|.*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\w+:\w+` Match `:` between 1+ word characters
- `\K` Clear the match buffer (forget what is matched until now to keep it)
- `\h*\|.*` Match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars, `|` and the rest of the line to be removed

[image]